# Mock in Unit Tests

Tags: юнит-тесты, mocking

i have a interface, and i need mocked one else interface in this interface. 
What is wrong? 
Есть интерфейс, мне нужен *макет* (?) в другом интерфейсе в этом интерфейсе. 
Что здесь не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй просто выбрать свойство другого интерфейса из первого

```
private void Mock_IImportConfigurationEmail()
    {
        autoMockContext
            .Mock<IImportConfiguration>()
            .SetupGet(get => get.Email.RecipientEmail)
            .Returns("asd");
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, тест проходит!!!